# Overriding in C#, making two subsequent method virtual

Tags: c#, overriding

It's a question of overriding in C#.

When I use following code:

```
class Program
{


    class A
    {
        public virtual void callme()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("this is A");
        }
    }
    class B : A
    {
        public new virtual void callme()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("this is B");
        }
    }
    class C : B
    {
        public override void callme()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("this is C");
        }
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A obj = new C();
        obj.callme();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:** `This is A`

And when I use:

```
class Program
{


    class A
    {
        public virtual void callme()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is A.");
        }
    }
    class B : A
    {
        public override void callme()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is B.");
        }
    }
    class C : B
    {
        public override void callme()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is C.");
        }
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A obj = new C();
        obj.callme();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:** `This is C.`

So if I make a method virtual in the subsequent classes (`A` as well as `B`), why it calls the last method, and if the `B` class is overriding `A` and `C` is overriding `B` then it's calling `C`'s method.

Please explain.

Comment: This is exactly why you should not ignore compiler warnings.

Answer (score 2):

In the 1st case, B is shadowing A and C is overriding the shadow in B. So as long as the reference type is A, it will call the A method.

In the 2nd case B is overriding A and C is overriding B (so it's overriding A).

See: [Differences Between Shadowing and Overriding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172785.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Check the compiler warning:

> Warning   1   '..Program.B.callme()' hides inherited member
>   '..Program.A.callme()'. To make the current member override that
>   implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new
>   keyword.  ..\Program.cs   44  33  Test

It states that method in B hides the method in A. When you override the method in C; it simply overrides the method in B not in A (compiler assumes that you `callme` in class B is a new method). So when you call `A.callme`, since the method in A is not overriden, it returns "this is A".

Comment: ..."When you override the method in C; it simply overrides the method in B not in A (compiler assumes that you callme in class B is a new method)"... This is incorrect. Only virtual method can be overriden so method from A class is overriden (not B) in this example. Class C just inherited this method from class B that inherited this method from parent class A...

Comment: @Fabjan method in B is also virtual, check the first example in the question, and it hides the implementation in A. your assumption is not correct; whether you use new keyword or not, method in B is a NEW method and has no relation with the method in A.

Comment: Oh sorry then. Haven't noticed it (upvoting you again)